# How to extract the user ids for each element

Tags: r, twitter

How can I extract the user_id from the retweets collected using this function?

```
## get only first 8 words from each tweet
x <- lapply(strsplit(dat$text, " "), "[", 1:8)
x <- lapply(x, na.omit)
x <- vapply(x, paste, collapse = " ", character(1))
## get rid of hyperlinks
x <- gsub("http[\\S]{1,}", "", x, perl = TRUE)
## encode for search query (handles the non ascii chars)
x <- sapply(x, URLencode, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
## get up to first 100 retweets for each tweet
data <- lapply(x, search_tweets, verbose = FALSE)
```

I have 12 elements, each contains a list of user ids, how can I extract the user ids only?

here is the full code:

```
library(rtweet)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
require(reshape2)

## search for day of rage tweets, try to exclude rt here
dor <- search_tweets("#Newsnight -filter:retweets", n = 10000)

## merge tweets data with unique (non duplicated) users data
## exclude retweets
## select status_id, retweet count, followers count, and text columns
dat <- dor %>%
  users_data() %>%
  unique() %>%
  right_join(dor) %>%
  filter(!is_retweet) %>%
  dplyr::select(user_id, screen_name, retweet_count, followers_count, text) %>%
  filter(retweet_count >=50 & retweet_count <100 & followers_count < 10000 & followers_count > 500)
dat

## get only first 8 words from each tweet
x <- lapply(strsplit(dat$text, " "), "[", 1:8)
x <- lapply(x, na.omit)
x <- vapply(x, paste, collapse = " ", character(1))
## get rid of hyperlinks
x <- gsub("http[\\S]{1,}", "", x, perl = TRUE)
## encode for search query (handles the non ascii chars)
x <- sapply(x, URLencode, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
## get up to first 100 retweets for each tweet
data <- lapply(x, search_tweets, verbose = FALSE)
```

[There are 11 more elements like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us3y8.png)

[12 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGJGY.png)

Comment: Are you saying `data` is a list of 12 elements? Can you show what `data` looks like?

Comment: @AlexP , I edited the question. I added a picture to show the data

Comment: Hmm... it says it is 79x39. Where are the 12 elements you speak of?

Comment: Can you select only the columns you need from that table? I have a feeling one of the columns is a list-column. `unnest()` might help.

Comment: @AlexP please see the 2nd attachment I added now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you have a list of 12 dataframes, each has a column called user_id. if the list is named, then this will work, if it isn't named, then take out the `df_name = names(data)[x],` part.

```
lapply(1:12, function(x) {
  df <- data[[x]]
  data.frame(user_id = df$user_id, 
             # df_name = names(data)[x], 
             df_number = x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) } ) %>%
dplyr::bind_rows()
```

That should give you a new dataframe with all of the userids and which previous dataframe they came from.

Comment: How can I add a 2nd column that shows to that dataframe this userid belongs?

Comment: I've amended my answer so that it should be about what you are now asking. If it works, please accept the answer.

Comment: its showing this: Error in x$user_id : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: my bad, line three should be  `... user_id = df$user_id,`

Comment: I am getting this now: arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1, I think because each dataframe has different number of rows

Comment: if `data` has no names, then you need to take out the `df_name = ...` bit

Comment: it makes no difference that the dataframes have different numbers of rows. I see from the screenshot you posted that the elements of the `data` list are unnamed. I'll edit my answer accordingly.